# Tell background script when content script injected with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I'm injecting a React component into a webpage as a script, but this is on a page that is opened via a background script.

What I am trying to do is wait until the page is loaded and the React component is mounted, then send a message to that component. Unfortunately, I can't get this working, so I suspect it's because Chrome says the page has loaded but the React component hasn't yet mounted.

In my background script I have the following:

```
function relist(request) {
    const url = 'domain.com';
    chrome.tabs.create({ url },() => {
        chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(reListener);
    });
    // Listen for new relist tab and remove listener when loaded
    function reListener(tabId, info, tab) {
        if(tab.url === url && tab.status === "complete") {
            console.log("Found tab");
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {action: "relist", data: request.data});
            chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(reListener);
        }
    }
}
```

Then within the component, I am injecting I have the following:

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log("Mounted Design Upload");
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
        (request) => {
            console.log("Received Message");
            if(request.action === "relist") {
                console.log("relist", request);
                this.props.dispatch(currentDesign({
                    id: request.data.design_slug,
                    meta:request.data.meta,
                }));
                this.setState({
                    value: {
                        key: request.data.design_slug,
                        name: request.data.design.title
                    },
                    selectedFile: request.data.file_slug
                })
            }
        });
}
```

Does anyone know how I can tell the background script to wait for the message from the component before sending the data across?

Comment: The `tab.url` may be slightly different (some pages/servers modify or redirect the urls) so try saving and checking `tab.id` instead. Also, non-inlined page scripts run after DOMContentLoaded event so your onMessage listener is registered too late. It might make sense to initiate messaging from the content script. For that, in your bg script you'll use a one-time onMessage listener that checks sender.tab.id instead of onUpdated.

Answer (score 2):

Use a long-lived connection between your content and background scripts.

Imagine a folder structure like this:

```sh
├── content
├───── AwesomeComponent.js
├── background
├───── index.js
├── messenger.js
├── manifest.json
```

You will have a script that sends/receives messages from both content and background scripts.

`messenger.js`

```js
import { relist } from 'background/index'

chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function (port) {
  port.onMessage.addListener(function (request) {
    if (request.action === 'mounted') {
       // this message was sent by your AwesomeComponent
       // call relist to send data to content script
       relist()
    }

    if (request.action === 'relist') {
       // this message was sent by your background script
       // dispatch an action with request.data using your state management library
       // this will trigger an re-render in your React app and update its props
    }
  })
})

const context = typeof chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage !== 'function' ? 'content' : 'background'

export function postMessage (request) {
  if (context === 'content') {
    const port = browser.runtime.connect()
    port.postMessage(request)
  } else {
    const port = browser.tabs.connect(request.tabId)
    port.postMessage(request)
  }
}
```

Include the `messenger.js` module in `content/index.js`. This will add a `chrome.runtime.onConnect` listener.

`content/AwesomeComponent.js`

```js
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'

import messenger from '../messenger'

class AwesomeComponent extends React.Component {
  // [...]

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    /* 
      Component was updated because a dispatch action was fired 
      through a message coming from the background script.
      Compare previous props and then use setState.
      You SHOULD compare them or it'll cause an infinite rendering loop!
      A comparison may be...
    */
    if (this.props.value.key !== prevProps.value.key) {
      this.setState({
        value: {
          key: props.design_slug,
          name: props.design.title
        },
        selectedFile: props.file_slug
      })
    }
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    // send a message to background
    messenger.postMessage({
       action: 'mounted'
    })
  }

  // [...]
}
```

Include the `messenger.js` module also in the background script `index.js`. This will also add a `chrome.runtime.onConnect` listener.

`background/index.js`

```js
import messenger from '../messenger'

export function relist (data) {
  const data = ...
  chrome.tabs.create({ url: 'domain.com' }, () => {
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function reListener(tabId, info, tab) {
      if(tab.url === url && tab.status === 'complete') {
        console.log('Found tab');
        messenger.postMessage({
          tabId: tab.id,
          action: 'relist', 
          data: data
        })
        chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(reListener);
      }
   }
}

// other background stuff
```